How to convert the data of speed versus time of electric vehicle to the data of battery current versus time？
I am a beginner in the field of lithium-ion battery system research. the Urban Dynamometer Driving Schedule (UDDS) is a specific driving condition of electric vehicle, which is composed of a series of data of speed versus time. Now, I want to use the UDDS to simulate the dynamic discharging process of a series-connected lithium-ion battery pack. How do I convert this data of speed versus time of UDDS into the corresponding data of battery current versus time? For example, in the link, https://github.com/Zhouzihao914/Equivalent_Circuit_Model_Battery/tree/main/udds, how is the udds_curr.mat obtained from the udds.txt.

According to the readme of the MATLAB code you have linked to, that code calculates the result you want from the vehicle details and the driving cycle data. The code doesn't load data from uds_curr.mat anywhere I can see and that file isn't mentioned in the readme.

Thank you very much for your comments. This file, udds_curr.mat, is loaded in  https://github.com/Zhouzihao914/Equivalent_Circuit_Model_Battery/blob/main/generateSytheticData.m
